# Shnayim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of chapters in [Kav HaYashar](http://hebrewbooks.org/24291). The word "kav," with a gematria of 102, hints to this fact. It also corresponds to the gematria of the author's first name, "Tzvi." (His second name, "Hirsh," is hinted in the word "HaYashar," which has the same letters.)

In the same vein, Rabbeinu Chananel (cited by Rosh, Eruvin 4:2) says that the rule which states that the halachah follows R' Eliezer ben Yaakov because his teachings are "kav venaki" (few in number but pure), is actually limited to 102 -- "kav" -- of his teachings.

Comment: Some more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kav_ha-Yashar

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8191.

Answer (score 5):

102 are the years that Lubavitcher Chassidus was headquartered in the town of Lubavitch (Cheshvan 5574/1813 - Cheshvan 5676/1915).

R' Shalom Dovber Schneersohn (the then Lubavitcher Rebbe) commented, upon his departure, that this number represents the numerical value of the word יסוד (foundation, basis) plus the 22 letters of the Hebrew alphabet, symbolizing the idea that "Lubavitch, during these 102 years, built a strong foundation with the 22 letters."

([Likkutei Dibburim, vol. 1, pp. 29-30](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39163&pgnum=36))

Comment: And R' Yehuda Chitrik zt'l was the last remaining Lubavitch chossid who'd studied in Lubavitch, no?

Comment: I believe so, yes. (The yeshivah actually remained in Lubavitch a couple of more years; it moved to Kremenchug in the summer of 1918.)

Answer (score 5):

Avraham was 102 at Yitzchak's weaning party

Answer (score 4):

Yefes was 102 when Shem begat Arpachshad

Answer (score 3):

Eved Hashem(yukeyvavkey) is 102 and the word emuna(alef mem vav nun hey) is 102 thus we learn from this that a true eved hashem will and must have emuna.

Answer (score 2):

*Nusach S'farad* says psalm 27 102 times a year as part of the prayer services: during *shacharis* and *mincha* daily from 1 *Elul* through *Sh'mini Atzeres*.

[I'm told](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10108) *Nusach Haari* also says it 102 times: at *shacharis* and *mincha* from 30 *Av* through *Hosha'na Raba*.